# Exclude parent categories from the_category() within the loop

Tags: wordpress

I have typical parent and child categories setup as follows:

- Food

  - potatoes
  - corn
  - beats
- Sports

  - soccer
  - football
  - hockey

etc.

In my index.php template I'd like to list the categories of the specific post. The problem is, when I use `the_category()` it lists the parent categories twice. I'm using the following code:

```
<php echo '<dt>', the_category(', ', 'multiple'), '</dt>', "\n"; ?>
```

And it prints out:

`Food:corn, Food, Food:potatoes`

I believe it is listing the child category "corn" as "Food: corn" followed by the parent category "Food" just as "Food." Is there a way to exclude the parent categories?

The way I'd like it to read is:

`Food:corn, Food:potatoes`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a single page that is in both a parent and a parent:child category.  Each page should only be in a parent:child category.  The parent archive can show everything in all of the parent:* categories.